# Write code locally, send to server

Tags: php, editor, commit

I'm trying to configure my web server and I'm a complete beginner. Now everything is working quite fine. I want to write some php files. But I only have unix command line access to the server and vim or nano are not really convenient for writing lines of codes.

So the question is :
- Is there a unix command line php editor i can "apt-get install" on my debian server ?
- Is there a proper way of writing files on my computer and then commit them to the server ?

Here I'm looking for an easy solution... As I don't have much knowledge about the subject !
Thanks !

Comment: Develop offline, deploy online. Use Winscp to upload your files or install a ftp-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, typically whoever is hosting your server will give you some kind of facility for uploading for files: FTP, SCP, etc. If someone else is running your server for you (e.g., a web host) you should contact them to find out what options you have. If you are administrating over the server yourself, you will need to install some kind of file transfer server on it. FTP would be the obvious choice, but not necessarily the best, especially if you have to connect to it over the public internet (FTP is not encrypted by default, so your file contents and even your login details will be sent in clear text over the network). If you are using SSH (e.g., PuTTY) to connect to your server, you should be able to use pscp to copy files securely.

But for what it's worth, Vim is super convenient for writing lines of code, once you know how to use it. Vim is a programmer's text editor, it's got loads of features that make writing lines of code easy.

Comment: Configuring ftp was easier than what I thought ! Thanks !